# how can I change color in Highlight state on a UIBarbutton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I want the change the color of my UIBarButtons in highlight state, But I cant get it to work. Right now I set the color using setTintColor and this set the color of my bar.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:108/255.0f green:108/255.0f blue:108/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
```

But when I try to change the color on highlight state it doesn't work, this is what im trying.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[UIColor colorWithRed:122/255.0f green:122/255.0f blue:122/255.0f alpha:1.0f] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: This answer may help you [http://stackoverflow.com/a/9503822/1884961](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9503822/1884961)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
[myButton setBackgroundImage:[self imageWithColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:122/255.0f green:122/255.0f blue:122/255.0f alpha:1.0f]] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

This may help you

Comment: It's just a button with text, does it work the same?